# Deploying different webapps by different ports in a single JBoss instance

Tags: jboss

I want to setup a single JBoss instance which serves a webapp in a given port and a backend webapp in another port.

I know how to config two ports for a single instance but I don't find any clue about how to match a port to an app in JBoss.

If it is not possible, I am going to do it with two instances but I would like to know this.

Comment: hi, 

referred to this site https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine

Dario,

could you please tell me how did you do to config two ports for a single instance?

really appreciate if you can help me.

thanks

tuelip